# True or False? The transformation $T$ on the set of all continuous functions that is defined by $T(f) = f (1)$ is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

**True or False?** The transformation $T$ on the set of all continuous functions that is defined by $T(f)= f(1)$ is a linear transformation.

Intuitively, I can see that this might be true if you plugin stuff like $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = \cos(x)$. Thus, $T(a_1\cdot x + a_2\cdot \cos(x)) = a_1 \cdot 1 + a_2 \cdot \cos(1) = a_1\cdot T(x) + a_2\cdot T(\cos(x)).$

But how do I definitely prove this? I have heard about arbitrary function arguments, but I don't know enough about functions to really make an argument here either way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be over-complicating the issue. Just check the axioms of linearity.

Assuming that by "continuous functions" you mean continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to itself, let $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ and $f,g \in C(\mathbb R)$.

$$\begin{align}T(f + g) &= (f + g)(1) = f(1) + g(1) \\
T(\lambda \cdot f) &= (\lambda \cdot f)(1) = \lambda \cdot f(1)\end{align}$$

Comment: I like this answer the best because I am over-complicating it. Thanks!

Comment: @JerryQu - If your question is answered, please click the check mark on the answer that best serves you.

Comment: I can't seem to accept it yet! It tells me to wait another 3 minutes. I will definitely do so!

Comment: @JerryQu - Haha, I didn't even know that was a feature! Alright.

Answer (score 5):

Let's simply verify that T is a linear transformation from the definition. Indeed, $T(af) = af(1) = aT(f), \text{and } T(f+g) = (f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=T(f)+T(g).$

Comment: Oh I guess I missed that (f+g)(1) = f(1) + g(1).

Answer (score 2):

$$T(f+g)=(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=T(f)+T(g)$$
$$T(cf)=cf(1)=cT(f)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it directly from the definition. You can also search it's name, evaluation functional. It's the third example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form